# Using Azure DevOps DACPAC task to run a SQL command on the master database of Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to add some users to an Azure SQL DB Server using an Azure DevOps Release pipeline.

Azure DevOps is used to build the infrastructure using a Service Principal connected to our subscription. This all works fine, but when I try to configure database users using the DACPAC task in DevOps, I get errors when I use the Microsoft Authentication (Integrated) Mode to authenticate.

If I use the SQL Server Admin Login in the task, the SQL Command runs, but I can't assign the users as the login I'm using is not an AD login.

I have tried making the AD Admin in the Azure Portal the Service Principal - this would make sense to me - but the task fails with an error that is related to authentication.

I also try to deploy a DACPAC rather than run a SQL Command and get a similar issue.

SQL Command I am trying to run:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = 'azSG-XXXX-Fred')

    CREATE USER [azSG-XXXX-Fred] FOR EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GO
```

Output is as follows:

```
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6287831Z ##[section]Starting: Azure SQL SqlTask
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6393885Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6394009Z Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6394095Z Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6394185Z Version      : 1.153.0
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6394249Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6394342Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment
2019-07-31T10:57:38.6394428Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-31T10:57:49.8641267Z Temporary inline SQL file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4A74.tmp
2019-07-31T10:57:49.8843725Z Invoke-Sqlcmd -connectionString "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=master; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;"  -Inputfile "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4A74.tmp" 
2019-07-31T10:57:52.7552260Z Sql file: D:\a\r1\a\BuildDirectory\SQLServer\azSG-XXXX-Fred.sql
2019-07-31T10:57:52.7583808Z Invoke-Sqlcmd -connectionString "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=master; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;"  -Inputfile "D:\a\r1\a\BuildDirectory\SQLServer\azSG-XXXX-Fred.sql" -Verbose
2019-07-31T10:57:52.9929063Z ##[error]One or more errors occurred.
2019-07-31T10:57:53.0718651Z ##[error]ManagedBatchParser.ParserException
   at ManagedBatchParser.Parser.Parse()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.ExecutionProcessor.ExecuteTSql(String sqlCommand)Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
2019-07-31T10:57:53.1217956Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure SQL SqlTask
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?